# Error with Sklearn Random Forest Regressor

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

When trying to fit a Random Forest Regressor model with y data that looks like this:

```
[  0.00000000e+00   1.36094276e+02   4.46608221e+03   8.72660888e+03
   1.31375786e+04   1.73580193e+04   2.29420671e+04   3.12216341e+04
   4.11395711e+04   5.07972062e+04   6.14904935e+04   7.34275322e+04
   7.87333933e+04   8.46302456e+04   9.71074959e+04   1.07146672e+05
   1.17187952e+05   1.26953374e+05   1.37736003e+05   1.47239359e+05
   1.53943242e+05   1.78806710e+05   1.92657725e+05   2.08912711e+05
   2.22855152e+05   2.34532982e+05   2.41391255e+05   2.48699216e+05
   2.62421197e+05   2.79544300e+05   2.95550971e+05   3.13524275e+05
   3.23365158e+05   3.24069067e+05   3.24472999e+05   3.24804951e+05
```

And X data that looks like this:

```
[ 735233.27082176  735234.27082176  735235.27082176  735236.27082176
  735237.27082176  735238.27082176  735239.27082176  735240.27082176
  735241.27082176  735242.27082176  735243.27082176  735244.27082176
  735245.27082176  735246.27082176  735247.27082176  735248.27082176
```

With the following code:

```
regressor = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=150, min_samples_split=1)
rgr = regressor.fit(X,y)
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError: Number of labels=600 does not match number of samples=1
```

I assume one of my sets of values is in the wrong format but its not too clear to me from the documentation.

Comment: can you print `X.shape` and `y.shape`?

Comment: print X.shape, y.shape:(600,) (600,)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The shape of `X` should be `[n_samples, n_features]`, you can transform `X` by

```
X = X[:, None]
```

Comment: You can also use `X = X[:, np.newaxis]`

Comment: @M.Massias Yes, actually `newaxis` is an alias for `None`

Comment: Hi @yangjie, I am newbie in machine learning.. Can you please tell me why we need to transform X?? What is the reason behind it.! Thanks in advance!.

Answer (score 2):

It is treating your list of samples X as 1 sample as a vector so the following works

```
rgr = regressor.fit(map(lambda x: [x],X),y)
```

There might be a more efficient way of doing this in numpy with vstack.