# Getting "ValueError: Number of labels does not match number of samples" when print statement confirms they're same size

Tags: python, pandas

The exact error is "ValueError: Number of labels=21 does not match number of samples=82", occurring on the line:

```
rf.fit(train_X, train_y)
```

Code is below:

```
df = pd.read_csv('C:\\git\\MetalRater\\Metal Sheet 2 - Sheet1 - TEST.csv', encoding="ISO-8859-1")

# The x and y are defined (x = features, y = y)
features = ["Emotion", "Solid", "Variety", "Length (mins)"]
y = df["RL"]

train_X, test_X, train_y, test_y = train_test_split(df[features], y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

print(len(train_X))
print(len(train_y))

def find_n_estimators(train_X, train_y, test_X, test_y):
    accuracy_forest_base = 0
    for i in range(10, 1000, 10):
        rf = RandomForestRegressor(random_state = 0, n_estimators = i)
        rf.fit(train_X, train_y)
        predictions_forest = rf.predict(test_X)
        for i in range(len(predictions_forest)):
            predictions_forest[i] = round(predictions_forest[i],0)
        accuracy_forest = accuracy_score(test_y, predictions_forest)
        if accuracy_forest > accuracy_forest_base:
            accuracy_forest_base = accuracy_forest
            n_est = i
        else:
            break
    return n_est
```

The print statement confirms that both are a length of 82.

EDIT: As requested below, I printed the following:

```
print(np.shape(train_X)[0])
print(np.shape(train_y)[0])
```

This yielded results of "82" and "()" respectively.

Comment: please print these in your question. 
np.shape(train_X)[0] 

 and 
np.shape(train_y)[0], where np is numpy

Comment: Edited above. It's output was 82 and (). Why does it not recognize the y as having 1 column?

Comment: You didnt handle the brackets properly in your print, check and re execute. print(np.shape(train_y)[0])

Comment: Changed it. Now I get 82 for both outputs.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are calling the function with the parameters in the wrong order.
Ps: i cant comment so i have to reply as a answer

Answer (score 0):

Please, see this post 
[Error with Sklearn Random Forest Regressor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32198355/error-with-sklearn-random-forest-regressor)

and the solutions ,

rgr = regressor.fit(map(lambda x: [x],X),y)